# How to iterate over array to build a url?

Tags: javascript, loops, url

I'm trying to fetch data based on the url.

Everything works except on: **let urlFilters**.

What I'm trying to do:

- iterate over the array: **filters** (if it's not null)
- save output in: **let urlFilters**

By now, the iteration seem to work. When I console.log(urlFilters) I get key-value-pairs like "filter=orange" or "filter=apple?". The problem: only the last key-value-pair is saved and thus used for the **url**.

My question: how can I save all the key-value-pairs from the iteration and use them all in the url?

```js
const getInfo = async(filters, searchTerm) => {
  let url = "";
  let urlBasis = "/api/productInfo?";
  let urlSearchTerm = "";
  let urlFilters = "";

  if (searchTerm.length !== 0) {
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  };

  //problem 
  if (filters.length !== 0) {
    filters.forEach((filterItem, index) => {
      urlFilters = `filter=${filterItem.categoryUrl}${index === filters.length -1 ? "" : "&"}`
   //console.log(urlFilters) -> "filter=orange" or "filter=apple&"
    });
  } else {
    urlFilters = ""
  };

  try {
    //problem urlFilters: shows only the last key-value pair
    url = urlBasis + urlSearchTerm + `${searchTerm.length !== 0 && filters.length !== 0 ? "&" : ""}` + urlFilters


  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

I already tried to use .map instead of .forEach. I also tried to use the spread operator. But it didn't work and I'm a little stuck. Any suggestions (also for code improvement) are appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you can iterate over your array easier via `.map` and then merge the array into a single string using `.join()`:

```js
const data = [{url: "apple"}, {url: "banana"}]
const url = `http://myurl.com?${data.map(item => `filter=${item.url}&`).join('').slice(0, -1)}`
console.log(url)
```

Note that `.slice()` ist needed to cut the last `&` character off the string.

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear! The url is a little more complex and I think that URLSearchParams is overall a simpler approach (the code looks cleaner and works - I've posted an answer with my solution). Thank you anyway for trying to help me!

Answer (score 0):

So I think my previous approach wasn't the best.

It seems as the **URLSearchParams**-API is a simpler approach when working with urls and params - at least with this solution the code works and looks cleaner.

Here is what I have now:

```
const getInfo = async (filters, searchTerm) => {
    let url = "/api/productInfo?";
    let params = new URLSearchParams();

    if(searchTerm.length !== 0) {
      //logic
    }; 
  
    if(filters.length !== 0) {
      filters.forEach((filterItem) => {
        params.append("filter", filters.categoryUrl);
      });
    };
  
    try {  
      url = url + params;
      console.log("url", url);
      ...
    }
}
```